# Error: Invalid form of PROGRAM statement at (1)

Tags: fortran

I am trying to run a fortran code with the below command:
 f95 -lm extrapolate3-node-irregularv2.f

and I got the below error

extrapolate3-node-irregularv2.f:1.14:

```
   PROGRAM extrapolate3c--------------------------------------------
          1
```

Error: Invalid form of PROGRAM statement at (1)

The beginning of my program like this:

```
  PROGRAM extrapolate3
  c------------------------------------------------------
  c  2nd step after runnin extrapolate-node-master...-v5(all dat).f
  c   so take the xxx-NODUP.dat file and proceed .. 
  c   ------- This extrapolates the int pts to the nodal values
  c   and then it outputs as per TECPLOT requirements~
  c ---------------------------------------
  IMPLICIT NONE
  integer tot_node,dim,tot_elem,d1
  parameter (dim=8,tot_elem=25,tot_node=72)
  INTEGER i,j,k,writecount,count
  DOUBLE PRECISION x(tot_elem*8),y(tot_elem*8),
 $     z(tot_elem*8)
  double precision val(tot_elem*8),d3
  integer kstep,KINC
  integer jelem(tot_elem*8),
 $     kintk(tot_elem*8)
  integer l_jelem,l_kintk(dim)
  double precision l_x(dim),l_y(dim),l_z(dim)
  double precision l_val(dim),l_nodal(dim)
  double precision xi(dim),eta(dim),zeta(dim),wvar
  double precision shfn(dim,dim),shfninv(dim,dim),one,eighth
  double precision det
  integer ii,jj,kk,err10
  integer conn(tot_elem,dim+2)
  double precision g_nodal(tot_node)
  double precision g_x_node(tot_node),
 $     g_y_node(tot_node),
 $     g_z_node(tot_node)
  double precision v1,v2,v3,dummy
  double precision l_x_node(dim),l_y_node(dim),l_z_node(dim)
  integer g_common_node(tot_node)
```

Did anyone meet the same problem before?

Comment: If you copied this from windows and aren't using a good editor that fixes your line endings, see the utility `dos2unix` to translate them manually.

Comment: You are using fixed form source.  Columns are significant, particularly for line continuation (and this looks like a line continuation issue).  You source code, as shown, has clearly incorrect columns, with the leading C for a comment being in the same column as the source proper.  Please edit your question so that the source code appears exactly as it is on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Look closely at the error message, which reports an error in the statement

```
PROGRAM extrapolate3c--------------------------------------------
```

which appears to be the first two lines of your program, i.e.

```
PROGRAM extrapolate3
c------------------------------------------------------
```

run together.  I suspect an invalid line-end or carriage-return character between the lines.  Do some editing, with a proper programmer's editor such as `vi` or `emacs` and make sure that all the whitespace in the source file is space characters (no tabs, no funny invisible non-printing characters) and all line-endings are, well, whatever is the default on your platform.  That kind of error sometimes occurs when copying source from, say, Windows to, say, Linux, and recompiling.